# RegExp to check for JavaScript

Tags: regex, sanitization

I need a java regexp to check for dangerous JavaScript in a text string so i don't save it in my database.
I'm trying to find some information on internet but can't find anything :(
Could somebody help me with that? 
Thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific on what kind of text you want to match?

Comment: Your database won’t execute JavaScript code. So don’t worry about that in that context.

Comment: Don't use RE for this; it's not built for that purpose.  Use a JS sanitizer of some sort. Since I don't have a name to give you I put this in a comment.

Comment: @Gumbo might they put sql code inside the js and get it executed in the db env?

Comment: @Keng: Possibly, but SQL-injections are not the context of this question. @Jake: You cannot trust _anything_ that happens on the client-side. One can easily bypass your validation. Sanitizing input should never be done client-side.

Comment: @Gumbo The OP may be concerned about his DB emitting malicious JS in markup at a later stage.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: I’m aware of that. But that’s not quite the task of the input validation for SQL data. @Jake: What is the purpose of the data that you insert into your database? Is it intended to be put into an HTML document?

Comment: I do use incoming data in server-side JS so i need this check before i pass it to the JavaScript. I hope you understand me now. Thank you for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I used some years ago a java class which appended for me a regexp like this:

```
(.(?<!<|%3c|&#x3c))*
```

It was computed that way:

```
   String[] EVIL_WORDS = { "<", "%3C", "&#x3C;", "&#60", "PA==",
                            ">", "%3E", "&#x3E;", "&#62", "Pg==",
                            "&", "%26", "&#x26;", "&#38", "Jg==",
                            "\"", "%22", "&#x22;", "&#34", "Ig==",
                            "'", "%27", "&#x27;", "&#39", "Jw=="};

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append("(.")
if(EVIL_WORDS.length > 0) {    
  buffer.append("(?<!");
  buffer.append(EVIL_WORDS[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < EVIL_WORDS.length; i++) {
    buffer.append('|');
    buffer.append(EVIL_WORDS[i]);
  } //for
  buffer.append(')');
}//if
buffer.append(')*');
```

It the pattern did not match there has been a bad character detected.

The script produced original a veeery looong regex and made checks for length, sql injection and a lot of other stuff, but these times have gone. With grails and XSS protection and hibernates sql injection protection I don't use it anymore.
But I am glad if I could help you.